# select box styling - css/jquery

Tags: jquery, css, forms, select

I've been hunting around to see if I can find a simple CSS or jQuery solution to achieve the following styling for a select box:

[image]

There are various items on SO such as the [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box), but these come close but the issue seems to be more with styling the "arrow" section of the select box.  Many of the samples I've found style the whole of the select field.

Is this really possible or feasible.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one that I just used recently.  It was pretty easy to theme.  It does involve using the jquery library on top of CSS.

http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/#themes

Note it doesn't work in IE6, but it degrades gracefully

Comment: Whilst I've ended up going in a different direction this certainly looks to answer the q.  Thanks

Comment: Who the hell still use IE6 ?? :P