# is it possible to edit the arrow which we get in the select tag (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is it possible to edit the arrow which we get in the select tag  (Rails)

I want to replace the arrow which we get in the select tag(drop down element) with my own image..

Is it possible to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that with the `<select>` tag. There're solutions to replace it with `<ul>/<ol>` and some Javascript.

See answers to question [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box).

Comment: I recommend this as a design pattern in general because every browser puts selects together completely different.