# Modify Dropdown with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, interface, menu, drop-down-menu

dear, 
I need to implement a dropdown list/menu like the one in this image:
http://img832.imageshack.us/i/dropdownd.png/
(a screenshot).
Is it possible to know how to do that? is it possible in JQUERY?

thanks in advance, 
Andrea

Comment: There are some good answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few good jQuery plugins that allow styling of select boxes. Many allow styling of all form elements, but a good one that is just for select boxes is [Select Puncher](https://github.com/quickleft/select_puncher)

A popular jQuery plugin for styling **all** form elements is [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/)