# How do I to customize the look of an asp.net DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, customization, styling

I've been given a design to implement in an Asp.net website, and I'm struggling with some elements, particularly the DropDownList. What's the best way to change the look? I'd prefer to do something server-side as opposed to javascript, but I understand at least some javascript may be necessary.

In the end, it should look like this:
[image: The list box as it should look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question - [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box).

The first answer points to a dead link, but the second answer suggests using JQueryUI.

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html

Comment: How do you apply jquery-ui selectmenu to the dropdownlist do you know?