# Customizing a select with Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, customization, drop-down-menu

I have been searching a lot and I cant find anything.

I would like to customize a select checkbox with jquery. Do you know how could I do it? Any page with a tutorial or if you could help me please?

I would like to customize the dropdown button and also the inside of the `<option>`. With CSS I cant do it and I was told that with jquery it is possible but I cant find it...

Thanks in advance!!

This is what I would like to customize with jquery:

```
<select class="select-dropbox" name="select-dropbox">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
    <option>option5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It looks like there are a couple of different questions here. You may want to break them up.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the jQuery UI library?  It makes customizing form elements much easier.  Here is the example page for a "splitbutton" which is basically a select:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

jQuery UI replaces the element with a div, which gives you lots of options in customization.  You would simply listen for a click on the drop-down button, and then code a list to show up, etc.

Here's a good example:

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/mb/splitbutton.php

Comment: Nahhhhhh!!! THANKS!!!!!!!!!! I spent so many hours searching on the web!! seeing so many tutorials and plugins and so on!! MANY THANKS!