# How to Customise select tag?

Tags: html, css, image, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)

[image: Select Tag]

I want to customise my select tag as like the image above which should looks equally in all browsers.

CSS:

```
.select-bg
{
  background:url(../images/select-bg.png) no-repeat top center;
width:350px;
height:47px;
}

.select-bg select
{
background:#ff0000;
}

<div class="select-bg">

<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>

</select>

</div>
```

I want the the above image as a background of a select box.

So, can you please help ?

Comment: There is no image attached.  Also, what have you tried by yourself?

Comment: image is attached very first at the top

Comment: What do you need help with? The question as it stands is very poor in quality - it is difficult to answer as you didn't identify where you are having problems. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Customizing a `select` element to this extent is not possible. You will need a JavaScript based alternative.

Comment: It's not possible without client side scripting. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you a are attempting here is impossible with pure `CSS` and `HTML`. What you are going to need is jQuery.

Here is a list of great [list](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/select-box) box plugins. This [one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/FancySelectbox) looks like the one you would like and is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Another jQuery plugin you may like, that has the extra advantage of being themable with JQueryui's themeroller is [fnagel's selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui).  It's the evolution of [this original](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/).  Visit that page with some example that look exactly like your sample (except for the color but it's themeable).

A (minor) inconvenience of those components is that their rounded corners are css3 based and won't be rendered in older ie's

Answer (score 0):

Its not impossible with plain CSS and HTML if you use some of the new fetures of CSS3.

With css3-gradients and border-radius you can style the select-element to look like your example.

However, this will not work in browsers that lack support, but should degrade gracefully i.e those browsers that do not support this will show a standard select-element.

Example:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper select { 
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
                  linear,
                  left bottom,
                  left top,
                  color-stop(0.42, #EA0B0B),
                  color-stop(1, #F8ADAD));

            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
                center bottom,
                #EA0B0B 42%,
                #F8ADAD 100%); 
            border-radius:10px; 
            border:1px solid #000; 
            outline:0; 
            padding:5px; 
            color:#FFF; 
            font-weight:bold; 
        }
        .wrapper select > option { background-color:#EA0B0B; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <select class="test">
            <option>first</option>
            <option>Second</option>
            <option>Third</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```