# jQuery / CSS: I need a plugin, that lets me change the style of a <select> form element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I want to use a good old  form element on my page. But I don't like the 
styling of it, how can I change it, is there quick way to do this in CSS, searched a lot, did'nt find a good answer, or do I need a jQuery plugin (which one?) ?

Thanks, 
Jakob

Comment: any wishes? what does it have to do more? what other look do you want

Comment: It's tricky to style selects, they are native to browsers. Goodluck with that!

Comment: @Emmanuel selects are easy, file inputs are hard ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can style a select element. it won't work cross-browser. The only way is to use JS to style it how you want it to look and then have it degrade gracefully without JS on. Note i have not tried using js/jquery to controlthe appearance of a select list - have no idea how well it will degrade in downlevel browsers.

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box) and [this site](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/)

[Jquery option](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't the type of question SO was created for.

Even so, I'm a helpful type: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/06/jquery-forms-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.noupe.com/css/form-elements-40-cssjs-styling-and-functionality-techniques.html

Answer (score 0):

It can all be done via CSS.

After a quick google search here is a resource with loads of examples in!

http://www.noupe.com/css/form-elements-40-cssjs-styling-and-functionality-techniques.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not css ??

```
select{
  color: gray; border: 1px solid blue; /*... other styling*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried styling it using CSS, and while you can style many parametres, you replace the image og the arrow for example..

Comment: If you want to customize the down arrow try this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectbox