# Customize HTML <select> with CSS

Tags: html, css, select, styling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)

I'm searching for a way to customize a select element in my HTML code.
I wanted my select to look like this:

[image]

I want the user to be able to see an image and two texts, which represents the first element of my list. Since this is supposed to be accessed by a smartphone (Android and Blackberry), I believe the list will open in the operating system component, so I don't have to bother styling the remaining options of my select, right?
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can accomplish quite as much as you want with just css styling a `<select>` tag. This is about how far it goes: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

I would suggest using other elements, like `<div>`s to accomplish what you want, and a little bit of javascript (jQuery, MooTools) for the added effects.

Comment: I agree with using CSS as much as possible, you want to avoid changing the select behavior for legacy purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a  [JavaScript image combobox](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown). The article is pretty straightforward, and i believe you can customize it even further than whats written in the article. Give it a shot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery plugin prettySelectBox, recommend it. http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/

Comment: That link has succumbed to link rot.

Answer (score 0):

Select elements are the ones which less customization acepts, so your freedom to style them is very limited.

In order to achive what you are looking for, I suggest you to build your own select-like component using custom HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

If you want to use an already existing one, I suggest you to take a look at the following links:

- [jquery-selectbox](http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/)
- [custom-combobox](http://code.google.com/p/custom-combobox/)

However, since what you are looking for is too specific, probably you will need to create your dropdown in your own.

Answer (score 0):

Styling selects is notoriously difficult - browser vendors have not allowed for widespread custom styling on form elements.

One way to get around it is to use javascript, maybe with a library such as jQuery.

There's some good answers and links to plugins on this page:
[Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<select>` tag is part of a larger set, called HTML form controls. They are different types of `<input>` tag, `<select>` tag, `<textarea>`. The most common known issues of HTML form elements (controls) is that, **they don't have cross-browser look & feel**. In other words, while a browser may animate a drop-down menu (a select element), another browser may open it up abruptly and at-once. Thus, a known web-design and development practice, is to create your custom controls, **from scratch** using simple elements and JavaScript (usually jQuery). Thus, I recommend that you create it on your own, instead of trying to find out how to make what you want (and to be honest, I think what you're looking for is not possible, since nesting **block-level elements** inside `<option>` tags are not allowed, if you want to have valid HTML).