# Stop select box from changing selected option color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down that I have styled with and image. When user selects an option it turns blue. The blue color shows on top of the image which looks really ugly. How can I stop this behaviour through css?? I dont want the selected state to change color.

I want something like

```
select:active {
    background:transparent;
}
```

I am open to javascript solution too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no agreed-upon, cross-browser, standards-compliant solution to styling a selected option from a select box.

Every browser handles input fields differently and that is most-true when working with select fields.

Your best bet will be to check out this question/answer: [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)

Comment: Is there a way to tell the select box to go behind image?

Comment: I don't believe there to be a sure method of making the color-change happen behind the background image.