# how to add style for ListBoxFor?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

How to add below style to below ListBox,

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableProducts, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableProducts, "Id", "Name", Model.AvailableSelected),
                         new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-bind", "options:availableProducts, selectedOptions:availableSelected, optionsText:'Name'" } })
```

**CSS**

```
div.selectbox-wrapper ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper ul li.selected { 
background-color: #EAF2FB;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper ul li.current { 
background-color: #CDD8E4;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper ul li {
list-style-type:none;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:2px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: also wanted to add width and height to List Box?

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery plugin to change the `<select>` element to a `<div>` with `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s.

Example is here: [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)