# Edit CSS Styling of HTML Select Button

Tags: html, css, forms, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)

I would like to know if it is possible with CSS to change the styling of a HTML select field.
I want to make the button with the arrow inside transparent but keep the arrow there, so basically removing the button look of the arrow.

Comment: Ok, how could I do it with JQuery?

Comment: How can this be marked as a duplicate when the "original question" was closed for being off-topic?

Comment: @ScottHallauer I realize you asked this 5 years ago, but I ran into the same issue. I realized that there are 100+ options for the appearance rule, one being -webkit-appearance: menulist-button. This prevented that default select styling, while also maintaining the caret. Then I made the background transparent. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible to accomplish cross browser with only CSS.

To get nice looking select fields you must use javascript.

There are a couple libraries for this:

http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/

http://uniformjs.com/

I am pretty sure you can find more if you just google for it.

Answer (score 1):

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

be sure to read the comments too, this will probably not work in old(er) browsers, jquery is the better solution