# Fully Accessible and Stylable Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, accessibility

I've looked at this: [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box) but it does not satisfy my needs of having a completely accessible select box that can be styled (Unless i missed something).

Before I embark off on my own control I'd like to check in here if anyone ever made or found a select that can satisfy the following requirements.

- Keyboard accessible and works like the normal select box. Fx Handles all of the following keyboard shortcuts http://access.aol.com/dhtml-style-guide-working-group/#combobox
- Allows both the drop down open menu content and drop down it self to be styled (including focus and hover states)
- Supports clickable labels.
- Works properly (as an aria-combobox) on Jaws, NVDA and Voice over

Every single one on the above mentioned link does not pass this criteria fully

Comment: Look into http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ and use CSS

Comment: Didn't check the code fully, but check out http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/combobox/index.php. If one of those pass, I recommnd posting your code as an answer so people can reference it.

Comment: The U Illinois one looks promising as a starting point. The select 2 one doesn't have the correct keyboard shortcuts and doesnt announce with screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

[StyleSelect](http://mikemaccana.github.io/styleselect/):

- Is keyboard navigable
- Appears in tabIndex by default
- Screen reads exactly the same as a regular select box, since it uses the `aria-hidden` attribute.

[image]

Many of the a11y browsers are proprietary, but if you'd like to test in them and [report if anything else needs adding](https://github.com/mikemaccana/styleselect/issues/1) the project will work on it (it also takes pull requests if you can fix it yourself).