# How can I change the background color of a selected option? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

When I select one or multiple options in select box in Firefox, the background of the selected options will be blue. But how can I change this background-color with CSS or JS?

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: not possible with native select box...

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="text" /><span>Item 1</span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="text" /><span>Item 2</span>

<style>
    input:checked + span {
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
```