# Style select box drop-down menu like a table

Tags: javascript, css, select, drop-down-menu, html-table

I am using a select box in my codes which contains 50 options, by default when I click on it, drop down menu appears like below:

```html
<select name="Select1" style="width: 56px">
 <option></option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select>
```

[image]

but I want it to appears like a table:

[image]

I tried some CSS and JS but didn't work, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a `<select>` element, no . . . HTML select boxes are some of the most limited, when it comes to cross-browser support for styling.  Even the most "flexible" browser are extremely restrictive on what they let you change (*some* font styling, *some* color support, sizing and spacing is about the most you should expect to get).

If you have to have a table-like structure, you are limited to using libraries or building a custom interface that mimic a dropdown (usually using styled divs and some flavor of "show/hide" or "slide" animation).  Here is another similar SO thread that has MANY suggestions to choose from: [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)