# how to make my select dropbox looks pretty?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div>
    <label for="vehicie_type">Vehicie Type:</label>
    <select id="vehicie_type">
      <option>11111</option>
      <option>22222</option>
      <option>33333</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="cc">CC:</label>
    <select id="cc">
      <option>11111</option>
      <option>22222</option>
      <option>33333</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

How can I make my select dropbox looks like the picture below?
What I want is the text and select box on different side and looks orderly.

[image]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Comment: not a duplicate: this is a request for general javascript, not a jquery-specific solution which the provided link is about

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post anything about your css.. something like this?

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
select {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="vehicie_type">Vehicie Type:</label>
  <select id="vehicie_type">
    <option>11111</option>
    <option>22222</option>
    <option>33333</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="cc">CC:</label>
  <select id="cc">
    <option>11111</option>
    <option>22222</option>
    <option>33333</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
select{
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    height: 25px;
    color: gray;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/3bnLuqcd/1/)**